# openssl configuration issue caused failure during certification by canaonical server

Tags: openssl, certificates, canonical

I have an openssl problem as below:

```
# pro --help
Failed to access URL: https://contracts.canonical.com/v1/resources?architecture=amd64&kernel=5.15.0-52-generic&series=jammy
Cannot verify certificate of server
Please check your openssl configuration.
```

What I can do to configure openssl correctly (in order to use ubuntu advantage tool which has already been installed here). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

change your locale and language to english from settings reboot and retry . you can be affected from utf8 locale bug

Comment: What bug your answer needs some details.